# Universal Image Loader - Viewpager NullPointerException in imageloader.displayimage

Tags: android, url, arraylist, android-viewpager, universal-image-loader

I got NullPointerException in line 98 in [pastie](http://pastie.org/7108410#94) and equal to line 191 in my locate `imageLoader.displayImage((String) myArr.get(position).get("image_url"), imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener()..`.

all my url I store it in `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`

full code http://pastie.org/7108410#94

Error

```
    03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at com.camitss.phnompenhcafe.ImagePagerActivity$ImagePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ImagePagerActivity.java:191)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:801)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:930)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:881)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1366)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4824)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4824)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4824)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2359)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1966)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1212)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1385)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1105)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4452)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
03-25 16:39:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(18178):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `ImageLoader imageLoader` is always null. You need to initialize it.

Try to replace:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader;
```

by

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
```

Comment: But I declare it already? and How to initialize it and with what?

Comment: @kongkea : put `imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(ImagePagerActivity.this));` in ImagePagerAdapter constructor

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK that won't work. You need to assign a value to `imageLoader` first, like `ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(...);`

Comment: @kongkea : see [Universal Image Loader for Android](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)  and initialize it according to ur need

Comment: @fiddler could you please help me? everything in full source code above

Comment: see my edit `ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();`

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using. @fiddler

Comment: the explanation is in the error message. please follow @ρяσѕρєяK's advice and read this: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1):

1. set a breakpoint in line 98 and verify that imageView is not null.
2. add a debug log message before line 98 and print out myArr.get(position).get("image_url") to see if this is a valid url and is actually not null.
3. when you set the breakpoint, verify that imageLoader is not null

As for how to debug in Eclipse, I would suggest looking at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8551818/312312) and the answers below

Comment: Did you check for the imageLoader pointer and the imageView pointer? Are they both not null?

Comment: how to check both imageLoader and ImageView?

Comment: when you set a breakpoint (you need to run the app in eclipse in debug mode), once eclipse hits the breakpoint it will stop. Put your mouse cursor over the imageView variable and it will display the value it has. Same for the imageLoader

Comment: When I move cursor over the `myArr` and `position` it show me value but I over on imageView it show a lot of items. I don't know which one that show me null image.