# App crashed when button clicked

Tags: java, android

I'm using onclicklistener and app crashes when I'm using the button...
the crash happens at the first page when I use it's only button.
Cant find the issue...
heres the mainActivity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final String str = ed.getText().toString();
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotesPage.class);
                intent.putExtra("username", str);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And the notespage:

```
public class NotesPage extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notespage);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String str = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        tx.setText("Hello"+str);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(NotesPage.this, Addnote.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.noteslist.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="NotesPage"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Addnote">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Logcat:

```
11-18 19:53:43.755: D/AndroidRuntime(1159): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-18 19:53:43.755: D/AndroidRuntime(1159): CheckJNI is ON
11-18 19:53:44.905: D/AndroidRuntime(1159): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
11-18 19:53:44.965: D/AndroidRuntime(1159): Shutting down VM
11-18 19:53:44.986: D/dalvikvm(1159): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 78% free 463K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-18 19:53:44.986: D/dalvikvm(1159): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-18 19:53:44.995: I/AndroidRuntime(1159): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
11-18 19:53:46.175: D/AndroidRuntime(1172): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-18 19:53:46.175: D/AndroidRuntime(1172): CheckJNI is ON
11-18 19:53:47.395: D/AndroidRuntime(1172): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-18 19:53:47.435: I/ActivityManager(91): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.noteslist/.MainActivity} from pid 1172
11-18 19:53:47.466: W/WindowManager(91): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21005
11-18 19:53:47.505: D/AndroidRuntime(1172): Shutting down VM
11-18 19:53:47.535: D/dalvikvm(1182): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
11-18 19:53:47.535: D/dalvikvm(1172): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 77% free 485K/2048K, paused 1ms+2ms
11-18 19:53:47.545: D/dalvikvm(1172): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-18 19:53:47.555: I/AndroidRuntime(1172): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
11-18 19:53:47.575: I/ActivityManager(91): Start proc com.example.noteslist for activity com.example.noteslist/.MainActivity: pid=1182 uid=10042 gids={}
11-18 19:53:47.945: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(91): setKernelCountSet(10042, 1) failed with errno -2
11-18 19:53:48.507: I/Process(91): Sending signal. PID: 1182 SIG: 3
11-18 19:53:48.507: I/dalvikvm(1182): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 19:53:48.675: I/dalvikvm(1182): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 19:53:48.955: I/Process(91): Sending signal. PID: 1182 SIG: 3
11-18 19:53:48.955: I/dalvikvm(1182): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 19:53:48.996: I/dalvikvm(1182): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 19:53:49.205: D/gralloc_goldfish(1182): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-18 19:53:49.275: I/ActivityManager(91): Displayed com.example.noteslist/.MainActivity: +1s789ms (total +9m33s430ms)
11-18 19:53:49.345: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(91): setKernelCountSet(10013, 0) failed with errno -2
11-18 19:53:50.705: D/dalvikvm(91): GREF has increased to 501
11-18 19:53:51.605: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3991K, 30% free 9843K/13959K, paused 7ms+17ms
11-18 19:53:53.545: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1182): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
11-18 19:53:53.545: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1182):   in android.widget.EditText@412bcf98
11-18 19:53:53.545: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1182):   0: sent at 1735495000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=1735495, downTime=1735362, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
11-18 19:53:55.975: I/ActivityManager(91): START {cmp=com.example.noteslist/.NotesPage (has extras)} from pid 1182
11-18 19:53:56.014: W/WindowManager(91): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
11-18 19:53:56.304: D/AndroidRuntime(1182): Shutting down VM
11-18 19:53:56.304: W/dalvikvm(1182): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.noteslist/com.example.noteslist.NotesPage}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:254)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at com.example.noteslist.NotesPage.onCreate(NotesPage.java:15)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
11-18 19:53:56.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1182):     ... 11 more
11-18 19:53:56.514: W/ActivityManager(91):   Force finishing activity com.example.noteslist/.NotesPage
11-18 19:53:56.535: W/ActivityManager(91):   Force finishing activity com.example.noteslist/.MainActivity
11-18 19:53:56.674: I/Process(91): Sending signal. PID: 1182 SIG: 3
11-18 19:53:56.694: I/dalvikvm(1182): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 19:53:56.754: I/dalvikvm(1182): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 19:53:57.044: W/ActivityManager(91): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4143f3e0 com.example.noteslist/.NotesPage}
11-18 19:53:57.055: I/Process(91): Sending signal. PID: 1182 SIG: 3
11-18 19:53:57.064: I/dalvikvm(1182): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 19:53:57.094: I/dalvikvm(1182): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 19:53:57.364: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(91): setKernelCountSet(10013, 1) failed with errno -2
11-18 19:53:57.607: D/dalvikvm(91): GC_CONCURRENT freed 458K, 11% free 11479K/12807K, paused 12ms+73ms
11-18 19:53:57.834: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(91): setKernelCountSet(10042, 0) failed with errno -2
11-18 19:54:02.674: I/Process(1182): Sending signal. PID: 1182 SIG: 9
11-18 19:54:02.824: I/ActivityManager(91): Process com.example.noteslist (pid 1182) has died.
11-18 19:54:02.834: W/InputDispatcher(91): channel '416022e0 com.example.noteslist/com.example.noteslist.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
11-18 19:54:02.845: E/InputDispatcher(91): channel '416022e0 com.example.noteslist/com.example.noteslist.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-18 19:54:02.915: I/WindowManager(91): WIN DEATH: Window{416022e0 com.example.noteslist/com.example.noteslist.MainActivity paused=true}
11-18 19:54:02.915: W/InputDispatcher(91): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '416022e0 com.example.noteslist/com.example.noteslist.MainActivity (server)'
11-18 19:54:02.974: I/WindowManager(91): WINDOW DIED Window{416022e0 com.example.noteslist/com.example.noteslist.MainActivity paused=true}
11-18 19:54:03.004: W/InputManagerService(91): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1182 uid 10042
11-18 19:54:03.717: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_CONCURRENT freed 421K, 30% free 9887K/13959K, paused 7ms+42ms
11-18 19:54:07.860: W/ActivityManager(91): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{41556b68 com.example.noteslist/.MainActivity}
11-18 19:54:07.860: W/ActivityManager(91): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4143f3e0 com.example.noteslist/.NotesPage}
```

Comment: Post the logcat. Also, "I've added the activity at the manifest..." make sure **all** `Activities` are added to the `manifest`

Comment: **Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'** the `manifest` said you what is the problem

Comment: asked 10 times a week ... read logcat again

Comment: could you add the mainActivity.xml the problem is in the declaration of the listview in the xml view file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NotesPage  is extends `ListActivity` not an `Activity` and y0u dont have any listview in your NotesPage

So Change the extends from `ListActivity` to `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

According to this line

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

you don't have a `ListView` with the appropriate `id` in `notespage.xml`. You should have something like

```
ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
```

When you `extends ListActivity` you must have a `ListView` with this `id`. If you only `extends Activity` then you don't need this.

**Off-Topic**

You can [see this answer about reading logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782558/what-is-the-best-way-to-debug-the-android-code-in-eclipse/16782621#16782621) this will give you a good place to start so you can debug more yourself and know what parts are most relevant when you still can't get it.

Also, you can filter your logcat by "error" to see the exception easier.