# no error shown but my application not running on emulation

Tags: android, android-intent

emulator shows " unfortuantely myapp has stop working "

earline was getting this line in console

```
Starting activity com.example.hotornot.SQLiteExample on device emulator-5554
```

but now GET THIS LINE.... can anybody tell me the error

```
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.hotornot/.SQLiteExample }
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1. you need to set `android:debuggable="true"` in your application in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. if you haven't set that setting, debugging will not be enabled.
2. either start the app by right clicking on the project and select Debug As->Android Application or by running it normally and later in the `DDMS` perspective select the running app in your devices pane and click on the green bug.

then please post the log cat here.

Source for steps:
[How to Debug Android application line by line using Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551818/how-to-debug-android-application-line-by-line-using-eclipse)