# getting SQLException during runtime and the program is running properly, also no messages in the logcat

Tags: android

I am new to SQLite. I am trying to make a simple application which uses SQLite database. I have completed most of the part, but I am getting some runtime exceptions.

Here is my java file for DBHelper-

Temperature.java :-

```
package com.example.sqliteexample;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class HotOrNot {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "item_name";
public static final String KEY_TEMPERATURE = "item_temperature";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HotOrNotdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "itemTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DBHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" ("+
                KEY_ROWID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, "+
                KEY_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                KEY_TEMPERATURE+" TEXT NOTNULL);"

        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
public HotOrNot (Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}
public HotOrNot open()throws SQLException{
    ourHelper=new DBHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase=ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}
public long createEntry(String name, String hotness) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_TEMPERATURE, hotness);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] 
                                {
             KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,KEY_TEMPERATURE
                                };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,null,null,null,null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iHotness = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEMPERATURE);
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iRow)+ " "+
        c.getString(iName)+" "+c.getString(iHotness)+"\n";

    }
    return result;
}
}
```

I am getting SQLException, while I was running the code. The code is syntactically good, but I can't understand, where its gone wrong.

This is what happened previously. But now, in addition to that, the application is not at all starting. No message is there in the logcat and status -

```
'ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.sqliteexample/.SQLiteExample }'
```

is missing in the console. Can any one please give me a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stop saying "syntactically good".  Exceptions aren't about that.  Accept that you and your code are wrong somehow.  Post the exception.  You'll get better answers.

Comment: what's the exception??

Comment: What is the message of `SQLException` ?

Comment: Where's the query?  I see no SELECT here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps

- you need to set android:debuggable="true" in your application in the
  AndroidManifest.xml. if you haven't set that setting, debugging will
  not be enabled.
- either start the app by right clicking on the project and select
  Debug As->Android Application or by running it normally and later in 
  the DDMS perspective select the running app in your devices pane and 
  click on the green bug.

then please post the log cat here.

Source for steps: [How to Debug Android application line by line using Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551818/how-to-debug-android-application-line-by-line-using-eclipse)

Comment: Thank you @Andrain, this worked for me, my application is running now. Thank you very much.