# Error on integer sharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Can someone help me understand why am I having an error when I use an `int` shared preference but when I use `String` it works fine?

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
int text = getPrefs.getInt("score", 3);
textView1.setText(text)
```

**EDITED**

Here's my logcat

```
        10-18 20:20:56.255: D/dalvikvm(6245): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2597 objects / 165960 bytes in 120ms
        10-18 20:20:56.625: D/AndroidRuntime(6245): Shutting down VM
        10-18 20:20:56.625: W/dalvikvm(6245): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thesis.logipic/com.thesis.logipic.Gameplay}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(ContextImpl.java:2706)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at com.thesis.logipic.Gameplay.onCreate(Gameplay.java:157)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
        10-18 20:20:56.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6245):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your textview text as follows:

```
textView1.setText(Integer.toString(text));
```

If you are only passing a `int` as parameter to a function that expects a `String` (or `CharSequence` in this case), you need to specify the conversion to String, otherwise the compiler doesn't know whether you are trying to use it as a String or if there should be a function `setText()` that expects `int` as the parameter.

If you combine your `int` with a String, like `setText("My value is: " + text);` then you don't need the conversion because the compiler can safely assume you mean to concatenate your `int` with the specified String.

Comment: I think you are confused about `parseInt`.

Comment: tried it but still gives me an error when I open the activity containing the code

Comment: You need to debug your code and try to find out what exactly is happening. Then post your question with the details of what you are trying to do and of your error. See here for tips on how to debug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551818/how-to-debug-android-application-line-by-line-using-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an `int` to [`setText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) which requires a `CharSequence`, usually a `String`.  This will not compile.

You need to convert your `int` to a `String`, usually through `Integer.toString(myInt)`;

---

The runtime error you are experiencing is because the underlying value is defined as a `String`.  Either you are populating it elsewhere as a `String`, possibly using [`setString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), or defaulting it as a `String`.

**See also:** [`SharedPreferences.Editor.putInt`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
textView1.setText(text);
```

To this:

```
textView1.setText(String.valueOf(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    int text = getPrefs.getInt("score", 3);
    textView1.setText(Integer.toString(text));
```