# i am trying to update my table's password for a given email value

Tags: android

my db file code is

```
public boolean insertUpdatedContact(String email1,String newpass){
    db=this.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
     args.put(COLUMN_PASS,newpass);
     int i= db.update(TABLE_NAME,args,COLUMN_EMAIL + "=" + email1, null);
     return i > 0;
}
```

and code for .java file is

```
helper.insertUpdatedContact(e,np1str);
Toast.makeText(this, "Modified Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
helper.close();
```

Comment: Please post the error you are getting if any. Are the values getting assigned to insertUpdateContact method ?

Comment: my app just stopped working... i.e. i get a runtime error  i hv checked there is no problem with the database

Comment: You should check debugger console to see the error.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551818/how-to-debug-android-application-line-by-line-using-eclipse

Try logging email1,newpass vaues to check wheter values are getting submitted